# MongoDB - Duplicate Key Error After Changing Model To Allow Duplicates

Tags: mongodb

I am using the mean stack. In Mongoose I defined a model with these properties:

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  personName:{ type: String, unique: true, required: true, index:true },
  start: { type: Date},
  end: { type: Date }
});
```

However, when testing I realised I had made a mistake and that personName should not be unique. I removed the `unique: true` property and restarted MongoDB and the app.

However, I still get the duplicate key error when submitting.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have created an index for the personName field.
Remove the index associated with field personName and try, it will work.

Reason:

when the field personName in the state "unique: true" index would be fine and now after removal of the state "unique: true". If we are trying to enter a record which is having a personName which is already there in the DB, then DB will throw Duplicate key error.

Comment: This worked. Thank you. I used the method documented here: [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-indexes/). I typed `db.people.dropIndex("personName_1")`